# Programming: How to alter printed text

Tags: text

In many programs, including many brute-forcers and the output of many commands, text which has already been printed to the screen is altered in front of you.
Using the brute-force example; the password which the program is currently attempting is cycled through extremely fast.

My question is: **How to alter text which has already been printed?**

Is there perhaps a function, or specific method by which this can be achieved? I have never encountered any code like it and it doesn't even seem possible from a programming perspective, however i am counting on being wrong.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: is this  string getting generated randomly or using dictionary of words?

Comment: The brute force example was using a dictionary, that being said, it involved text which was printed to the screen being altered repeatedly, which contradicts much of what i thought possible with programming, i was under the impression that once a string is printed, it cannot be altered in any way.

Answer (score 0):

A carriage return char should be printed (`\r`), and the output should be flushed.

In python, this can be accomplished specifying the `end` flag to `\r` and `flush` to `True`.

```py
print("sample text", end='\r", flush=True)
```

In a more generic way, any language should be able to access sys functions, in which case the `\r` should be added manually, and then the `flush()` function should also be called manually.